# Loop Issue - Remote Server

Tags: powershell

I wrote a small script to get some basic information off a few remote servers. But my output it is a bit odd. I believe my issue is with my `$DRIVE` function.

**Code:**

```psh
$serversList = 'svr01.xxx.com', 
               'svr03.xxx.com', 
               'svr05.xxx.com', 
               'svr06.xxx.com', 
               'svr08.xxx.com'
               #End of Server List

Write-Output "Start of Hal0 `n";

ForEach ($server in $serversList) {
    $OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
    $SYSNAME = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server).SystemName
    $DRIVE = {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server | 
            Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
            Select-Object DeviceID, Description,`
                @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
                @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}} |
            FT -AutoSize
    }
    $server + ' | ' + $SYSNAME + ' | ' + $OS + ' | ' 
}

Write-Output "`n End of Hal0";
```

**Results:**

```
Start of Hal0 

svr01.xxx.com | SVR01 SVR01 SVR01 SVR01 | Mic
rosoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise | 
svr03.xxx.com | SVR03 SVR03 SVR03 SVR03 | Mic
rosoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise | 
svr05.xxx.com | SVR05 SVR05 SVR05 SVR05 | Mic
rosoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise | 
svr06.xxx.com | SVR06 SVR06 SVR06 SVR06 | Mic
rosoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise | 
svr08.xxx.com | SVR08 SVR08 SVR08 SVR08 | Mic
rosoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise | 

 End of Hal0
```

What I was hoping my result would be a clean System Full Name, System Short Name, OS, Hard Drive Free/Used Space for each of the 5 servers.

```
svr08.xxx.com | svr08 | Windows 8 | C: 1111 MB Free/500 MB Used, E: 11 MB Free/10 MB Used.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never output `$DRIVE` anywhere, and the expression for `$DRIVE` shouldn't be in a scriptblock in the first place. The computer name is repeated several times, because you get the `SystemName` property for each logical disk object. Also, `$OS` gets the OS name for the local computer, not the remote computer.

Change your code to something like this:

```psh
$serversList | ForEach-Object {
    $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB), [int]($_.Size/1GB)
             }

    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN'            = $_
      'ServerName'      = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'Disks'           = $disks -join ', '
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

If you want the output echoed instead of written to a file use `ConvertTo-Csv` instead of `Export-Csv`.

---

**Addendum:** If you want to import the output file in a database use commas as the field separators for the CSV and join the disk information with some other character:

```psh
$serversList | ForEach-Object {
    ...
    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN'            = $_
      'ServerName'      = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'Disks'           = $disks -join '|'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is working right now but it is producing an odd output. http://imgur.com/QoNWp5G

Comment: @TheAce If you want to open files with the extension .csv in Excel the files *must* use `,` as the delimiter. Change the extension to something else (.txt for instance) and you can specify which characters are delimiters when opening the file in Excel.

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar I opened it in notepad and it looks a lot better. My question now is how can I push this new information "ServerName"|"FQDN"|"Disks"|"OperatingSystem" to a SQL table?

Comment: Make the output an actual CSV (i.e. use commas as delimiter for the fields and join the disk information with some other character). Most DBMS provide means to import CSV into database tables.